# Include opcional do Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com uma grande dúvida aqui no que diz respeito ao `Include` do Entity Framework.

```
var ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencia
       .Include("Pessoa")
       .Where(c => c.Id > 1000).ToList();
```

Usei o `Include`, pois preciso do objeto `Ocorrencias` com a propriedade `Pessoa` preenchido (Se existir pessoa), se não existir a pessoa, a regra de negócio irá tratar.

Minha consulta deveria retornar 12 registros. Contudo, quando uso o `Include` o retorno da consulta são seis registros, (apenas os registros que contém a propriedade `Pessoa`).

Como faço para que o `Include` faça o trabalho de preencher a propriedade somente se a mesma existir mantendo meu retorno correto?

Segue a model:

```
public partial class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
}



public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nome"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome da Pessoa")]
        public string nome { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        public string cpf { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que isso não é por causa do `where`?

Comment: Você tem como postar as models? Ao menos a parte que faz a ligação de ocorrência com pessoa.

Comment: Tenho certeza sim que não é por causa do Where. Absoluta. 
Model postada

Comment: Você pode postar a outra model também?

Comment: Adicionado. Cortei algumas variáveis para simplificar a model.

Comment: Perfeito. A ideia é deixar o mais simples possível mesmo, só que precisava manter a declaração da model `Ocorrencia` :p

Comment: Ou `Ocorrencia` tem `Pessoa` mas `Pessoa` não tem `Ocorrencia`?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Relacionamento Many to one.

Comment: Isso é estranho porque o Include faz um `Left Join`, seria bom você ver a *query* que é executada e tentar entender qual é o problema.

Comment: Você desabilitou o Lazy Loading?

Comment: Se for SQL SERVER, veja pelo SQL Profiler para identificar a query que está sendo executada. No Application Name aparecerá Entity Framework e você poderá ver o que ele realmente está fazendo. Ao abrir o Profiler, vai em File -> New Trace -> Abrirá a Trace Properties e clique em Run. Aí é só observar, após a execução de sua rotina com EF. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cajMz.png

Comment: @jbueno pelo SQL Profiler está fazendo um inner join. Não um Left Join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, não se trata de um Include opcional. Se trata de uma propriedade que aceite nulo.

O erro estava na `Model`, pois não permitia nulo, por isso a query estava sendo criada com o `InnerJoin` e não `LeftJoin`.

Desta maneira, o `Include` tratou corretamente, e após alterar a Model para permitir nulo, o retorno ficou correto.

Segue a model com a correção.

```
public partial class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public int? PessoaId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Eu ia responder de novo, mas você já fez isso. +1.